# Why does my new state wrapped in action-named property?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux and I don't understand does my code working well or I have some problems with it. That what I want to do:

I want to dispatch `addTodo` action inside `AddTask` component to change state. So I use that:

```
export default connect(
  null,
  { addTask },
)(AddTask);
```

Then I want to pass props from updated state to `Feed` component. So I use that:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
  return { tasks: state.addTask.tasks };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
)(Feed);
```

I think that it is strange that to access tasks property I should write `state.addTask.tasks` (not a `state.tasks`). Is it a problem with my code, or it is how redux works?

Comment: I think this has something to do with how you're returning the state object in your reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `state` object should contain your reducers, not your actions. They can by named whatever you like by assigning property names in `combineReducers`.

**src/reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import taskReducer from "./taskReducer";
import otherReducer from "./otherReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  tasks: taskReducer,
  myOtherReducer: otherReducer
});
```

These are the properties you want to pull off in `mapStateToProps` to get access to your state. Your *actions* need to be passed as an object into the `connect()` function as the second argument. Basically you have to combine the two things you were trying to do:

**src/components/Feed.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { tasks: state.tasks };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addTask },
)(Feed);
```